# IKEV2 VPN Macbook/OSX add static route, Azure Point to Site connectivity

Tags: macos, azure, vpn

I am unable to access all of the resources in my peered network in Azure when I do a VPN from macbook (VPN type IKEV2) have tried add routes didn't worked.

In windows to get this working was to edit the routes.txt file and add static routes in.

How will I go adding the same in Mac.

System Details
Mac osx - 10.13.2

Looking for
Ability to add/define static routes for my peered virtual network for IKEV2 type VPN in mac.

Comment: i believe you have to add that manually or run a script to that for you after "dial". /sbin/route add -net <route> -interface $1

Comment: tried that as well $1 is not getting accepted as interface but thats fine have got this one replaced. Can you help me or guide me on how to add a permanent route cause I dosconnnect the vpn the route goes off as well no surprises. Still struggling to put a route though

Comment: Try this one http://meinit.nl/add-permanent-static-route-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

We found a bug in the P2S VPN gateway that prevent this from working out of the box. The fix is currently being rolled out in Azure. You can wait until next week when we complete the rollout, or open a Service Request from Azure Portal and our support engineer can apply the fix directly to your Azure Gateway. Sorry for the issue you are running into.

Thanks,

Yushun [MSFT]

Comment: do I have to reset or reconfigure the client as I still seem to have issues with this